# Reading 500 inputs on one line via std::cin produces garbage

Tags: c++, c++11, cin

I have a very simple program:

```
int n;
int arr[1000];
cin >> n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
}
```

This works as expected for small inputs, but as soon as n > ~500 the input turns into upside down question marks as I type. It seems like the fact that the input is separated by spaces makes a difference because if I input 250 numbers, hit return, and then enter the next 250 numbers it works as expected.

Anyone know why this is happening?

EDIT: Thanks for the advice on checking to see if my terminal is borked; it turns out it is. Just running `./a.out < input.txt`
instead of trying to run the program via Xcode makes everything work fine using the exact same input.

Comment: The problem is likely with your terminal or you have undefined behavior in your code (i.e. exceeding the bounds of `arr`).

Comment: You can look (cout) arr[i] for odd i's to see if all of them equal to (int)' '  (char-to-int converted number of space).

Comment: It must be your terminal if it happens as you type - the input won't normally be sent to the C++ program until after you've hit enter....  What terminal are you using?

Comment: I was running the program using Xcode.

Comment: Please don't edit your answer into the question. Instead, accept a posted answer; or if there is no good posted answer then you can write your own answer and self-accept.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31916697/cross-arm-gcc-compiling-in-eclipse

Comment: @tolou.sobh Why the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"... if I input 250 numbers, hit return, and then enter the next 250 numbers it works as expected. ..."*

Doing so sounds pretty error prone for simple typos in input or such. Manually typing in that large amount of numbers is likely to fail from a strayed unwanted character or such.

You should check the actual results of the input

```
 while(!(cin >> arr[i])) {
     cin.clear();
     std::string dummy;
     cin >> dummy;
     cerr << "Invalid input: '" << dummy << "'." << endl;
 }
```

or simply stop processing in case of errors encountered:

```
if(!(cin >> arr[i])) {
     cin.clear();
     std::string dummy;
     cin >> dummy;
     cerr << "Invalid input: '" << dummy << "'." << endl;
     break;
 }
```

Comment: @CaptainObvlious THX for painting out, fixed.

Comment: YVW. I'm not sure this is going to be the solution though. It sounds like they get odd glyphs when they exceed a certain number of characters in the input buffer. Could be a borked C++ library, borked terminal, or even a garden gnome.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious at least that caveman debugging style should help to find what makes `cin >> arr[i];` unhappy and get further clues, what's actually wrong with the input. One could decide as well simply breaking the outer for loop for such case, and stop further processing.